# Displaying Custom Posts

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, navigation

I came across a strange problem while working on my dev environment for a site we're making. We have custom post types, so I'm not sure if that's the reason why it's not working correctly.  However, I managed to get the posts to display 5 at a time instead of normal 10.  However, in one of the categories, it only displays 10 out of 20 posts.  What's weird is that if I go to a different category, it'll run correctly.

```
    <?php echo category_description(); ?> 
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?> 
<?php $i = 0; while (have_posts() && $i < 5) : the_post(); ?> 
<div class = "post">
  <h3 class="listing-<?php the_ID(); ?>"> <br>
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title(); ?>"> <?php the_title(); ?> </a>   </h3>  </br> 
<div class = "city"> <b> City:</b> <?php $City = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'City', true); echo $City;?>   </div>
<div class = "price"> <b> Price:</b> <?php $Price = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Price', true); echo $Price;?> </div> 
<b>Rating:</b>
<div class = "rating">  <?php wp_gdsr_render_article(); ?> </div>
</div>   <br>
</br>
<?php $i++; endwhile; ?>
<div class="navigation">
 <div class="alignleft">
<?php previous_posts_link(); ?>
<?php next_posts_link(); ?>
</div>
```

**Answer**: 
Thanks for the help everyone!

The way to get around it is to go to:
 `WP Dashboard > Settings > Reading` and change the number at "blog pages show at most" option to the number of pages to display.

Comment: The number of post displayed is controlled first by the number set in the reading settings and can be overridden in your query using [posts_per_page](http://wordpress.org/search/posts_per_page?documentation=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your query is selecting 10 posts per page, but you're only limiting the view to 5, so you're losing 5 posts per page. The proper way to change the number of posts per page is to modify the query before the loop:

```
<?php
$myquery = wp_parse_args($query_string);
$myquery['posts_per_page'] = 5;
query_posts($myquery);
    if (have_posts()) : // etc.
```

Comment: Thanks Chris and Milo - unfortunately after I tried the query posts_per_page it remains the same. For the category I'm having issues with, I noticed it says "Nothing found..for category...page 3."

Comment: have you changed `while (have_posts() && $i < 5)` to `while (have_posts())` to verify that posts per page is being set correctly?

Comment: Sorry, I did change it back to while (have_posts()) but it didn't do anything different. It still displayed up to 10 posts_per_page, but never makes it to 20 posts.